# Alterar tag "symfony2" para "symfony-2"

Tags: debate

Recentemente, alterei algumas perguntas que estavam com a tag `symphony-2`: removi essa tag e adicionei tags com o nome correto do framework: `symfony` e `symfony2`.

Entretanto, como o @bfavaretto bem me lembrou (e eu não havia lido o tópico a respeito), nomes compostos, incluindo números de versão, devem ser separados com um traço. Sendo assim, o nome correto para a tag `symfony2` deveria ser `symfony-2`.

Num primeiro momento tentei simplesmente alterar a tag, mas o site não permitiu, alegando que a tag `symfony2` "já existe". Então, removi essa tag de todas as perguntas para que ela deixasse de existir. Entretanto, mesmo removendo as tags, a tag `symfony2` continua existindo (mesmo não tendo nenhuma pergunta vinculada a ela) e, consequentemente, não consigo adicionar a tag `symfony-2`.

No final das contas: alguém poderia, por gentileza, alterar a tag `symfony2` para `symfony-2`? :)